# How can I preview an HTML/CSS file in the Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud9-ide

My EC2 instance home directory has a index.html file. I just want to be able to periodically preview it in a browser/iframe while I'm making changes, using the Cloud9 IDE. Similar to how you can open up an HTML file with Chrome on a PC. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Just got a response for AWS tech support. Pasting it here for future reference too:

Try selecting the index.html file and then from the menu bar choosing Tools, Preview, Preview File index.html. The rendered HTML displays in a preview pane.

For more information, see the AWS Cloud9 User Guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/file-preview.html